# Which expiry interpolation method for caplet/floorlet surfaces?

Tags: volatility-surface, caplet, cap

I want to bootstrap an (implied volatility) caplet/floorlet surface from quoted cap/floor volatilities on a fixed strike grid. I'm thinking about either using a left-continuous or a linear interpolation in expiry dimension. If one just looks at the smiles of each quoted cap expiry left-continuous (1st picture) seems to be preferable as the linear smiles (2nd picture) are more spiky. However, a left-continuous interpolation will produce theta jumps. The jump always happens for a (standard) cap in the portfolio on the day when it's schedule aligns with schedule of the caps used to bootstrap the surface.

Therefore, out of these 2 candidates, I would go for the linear expiry interpolation. Does anybody have an opinion on that?

How about linear interpolation in variance. As each caplet has a different underlying rate, there is no direct problem with calendar arbitrage. Is linear interpolation in variance nevertheless the better choice than linear interpolation in implied caplet volatility?

Thanks,
Bernd

p.s.: I know that there are more fancy interpolation methods out there (e.g. using SABR smiles with interpolation on the SABR parameters) but I want to go for a simple interpolation as a starting point

[image: Left-Continuous Expiry Interpolation]

[image: Linear Expiry Interpolation]

Comment: What software do you use for the plots, if I may ask?

Comment: I use DevExpress packages within custom C# code

Comment: Are DevExpress packages paid? I had a quick look on their website and it seemed like free version is not available?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you have to pay for them